# Javascript- How to write a function that finds the max number in any set of numerical arguments

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, arguments, max

I am completing an exercise on JavaScript Hero (https://www.jshero.net/en/success.html) and I was able to get the function to work, however, I'm hoping someone could tell me WHY it works. I'd really appreciate it.

The challenge is...
*"Write a function max that calculates the maximum of an arbitrary number of numbers.
Example: max(1, 2) should return 2 and max(2, 3, 1) should return 3."*

My answer is...

```
function max (){

    let ans=0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] > ans){
            ans= arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

What I don't understand is setting ans to zero and then saying if arguments[i] is greater than zero then that is the answer. Wouldn't theoretically the first argument over zero be returned as the answer? Also, what if your passed in arguments are negative numbers, (-1,-5,-15) for example? Would the function not work then?

I would really appreciate any input on this. Even though I got the right answer, I want to understand what is going on in the code. Thanks! :)

Comment: maybe some constraints are given, like no negative values or at least one argument.

Comment: a more appropriate solution would set the initial `ans` to be the first element of the array, and then loop from element 1 onwards.   (likely returning `undefined` if the array is empty)

Comment: You should properly indent your code, you'll see the for loop over args. Also yes, for negative numbers this will fail. Try to init ans as NaN, and in the loop check if it is NaN before the actual greater check

Comment: Alnitak- Great adivice. Thank you. I tried that and it worked for all negative numbers as well. 
Netizen- Thank you for your answer. Could you explain that last sentence a little more? I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the first paramter as local max value and iterate from the second parameter.

```js
function max() {
    let ans = arguments[0];

    for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] > ans) {
            ans = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

console.log(max());
console.log(max(3, 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `ans` is only 0 initially. The value of `ans` changes on each comparison.

So, say you pass the array `[1,2,5,4]` to the `max` function, this is how it will go down:

- Is 1 bigger than 0? Yes, so `ans` becomes 1.
- Is 2 bigger than 1? Yes, so `ans` becomes 2.
- Is 5 bigger than 2? Yes, so `ans` becomes 5.
- Is 4 bigger than 5? No, so `ans` stays 5 and is returned to the user as the largest number.

Comment: So you're saying ans= arguments[I] is part of the loop and therefore ans only changes when the condition (if (arguments[I] > ans) is met? If so, that makes sense. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, so `ans` only changes whenever it becomes compared with a value larger than it. As others have said, there's a few use cases with this code that will lead to error or bugs but from a learning standpoint it's does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to compare two numbers at a time to determine which number is greater.
The code that you provided would only work if all the numbers in the argument are positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function max_val(arr){
    
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        
        for (let j=0;j<arr.length;j++){

           if (arr[i]>arr[j]){
             arr[j]=arr[i];
           }
        }
    }
    console.log(arr[1]); 
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.